# qr code reader using INTel-XDK

Tags: angularjs, cordova, qr-code, intel-xdk

I am new to mobile development and am using `Intel XDK` IDE, I have been asked to create a cross platform app that can scan `QR CODES` and after successfully scanning it should have two buttons that give the users options to `SAVE` to Points of interest or to `NAVIGATE` to the scanned qr code information.

Comment: what is your question? what have you done so far? you are not really want somebody to put a complete application code for you, aren't you?

Comment: And what is your question? What have you tried so far? Can you provide any code and point out a specific problem? We will not do your homework.

Comment: we are glad for you, you have a nice task. but this is not facebook ;) is there a question?

Comment: i have built a reader/Scanner but now my am stuck on how to save the scanned data as well as how to connect to gps navigation for the scanned qr code, so my question was how do i go about tackling it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start by looking at the sample app "Barcode Scanner".  Go to the "Projects" page and start a new project.  Then under "Samples and Demos" select "General".  Then choose "HTML5 + Cordova" in the main panel, and "Barcode Scanner" should be there.

If you start with this sample, you should be able to read barcodes, then you can add whatever you want to do with them.